# Filter distinct objects from ManyToMany within ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have following Models in my Django DRF app.

```
class FilterValue(models.Model):
  code = models.Charfield(…)

class ProductVariant(models.Model):
  filters = models.ManyToManyField("FilterValue", blank=True, …)

class Product(models.Model):
  variants = models.ManyToManyField("ProductVariant", blank=True, …)

  category = models.ForeignKey("Category", blank=True)
```

And I’m trying to define function on `Category` model which will return all objects of `FilterValue` attached to all `ProductVariants` of all `Products` that are assigned in the category.
Since I’ll have loads of different ProductVarints I can’t get away with nested loops since it’d be really slow.

I had multiple attempts to solve it.

I can of course get all `Products` within a `Category` using:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(category=self)
```

But then I get stuck on the fact that I actually need to filter nested ManyToMany object since I need all ProductVariants of all Products in the QuerySet and then - in the another level I need all ManyToMany FilterValue objects of each ProductVariant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) on how to query many-to-many relationships.

Try this to solve your problem:

```
filters = FilterValues.objects.filter(productvariant_set__in = ProductVariant.objects.filter(product_set__in = Product.objects.filter(category=your_category)))
```

Comment: Thank you for a very quick response and suggestion! I didn't know about `_set`. But it doesn't work as expected. It throws `AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'`. When I try following `ProductVariant.objects.all().first().product_set.all()` it's okay and returns all `Product` instances. But generally it more seems to return QuerySet of `Product` instances instead of `ProductVariant` if you know what I mean.

Comment: @MichalPůlpán, I changed the answer, you'll need to nest the reverse queries in the filters.

Comment: It sadly doesn't let me filter on `productvariant_set` but I might have found solution. Not sure if it's that effective, but it works way faster then my previous solution. It's `FilterValue.objects.filter(pk__in=some_category.products().values_list('product_variants__filters', flat=True))` Thank you for all the input and introducing me `_set`!